# Use NN2 from RANN library to predict test data

Tags: r, knn

I am trying to use the NN2 function from the RANN package to make a classification on test data based on the training data. My code for it is below.

```
 #Gets the library 
 library(RANN)
 # training model. Returns a list of indexs and distances
 fit.train <- nn2(train[1:10,], k = 3)
```

I have tried using the predict function but it does not work for lists. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

nn2 only working on data .frame or matrix, try cbind() list to a matrix.